# Test several functions with the same list of value with quickCheck

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

Is it possible with quickCheck to perform tests on several function with the same list of value with the aim of making a benchmark on these function ?

For example, I would like `prop_test1` `prop_test2` `prop_test3` to be checked with the same list of arbitrary values.

```
quickCheckWithResult args prop_test1
quickCheckWithResult args prop_test2
quickCheckWithResult args prop_test3
```

Comment: What do you mean with “making a benchmark”? Do you want your quickcheck test to fail if the runtime of the functions is not the expected?

Comment: I would like to validate 2-3 versions of a function with the same list of value and in the wake, comparing the speed of these differents version. To be accurate and strict, I would like to use the same list of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't insist on using QuickCheck, [SmallCheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/smallcheck-1.1.1/docs/Test-SmallCheck.html) might be your way to go. It's the QuickCheck for (bounded) exhaustive checks and will always produce the same test values (when used with same parameters).